# error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Multimedia.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shared-libraries

I have a 32-bit linux Virtual Box which I am compiling my Qt c++ code on.

I am copying the target files to a 64-bit linux box (the 32-bit executable should still run on this PC).

The build is using dynamic linking, so I was going to start copying across the Qt lib files that I need. I planned to just do this manually by running the program and letting it tell me which lib files are missing + I know many of the files that I need so it won't take me long (normally).

So in my 64-bit box target folder I have the files:

```
Rpe
```

So I run my executable called "Rpe" and it complains:

```
./Rpe: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Multimedia.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I expected this to happen, then I go and copy the file libQt5Multimedia.so.5 from my 32-bit linux qt lib folder into the target directory on my 64-bit linux box. In my target folder I now have the files:

```
Rpe
libQt5Multimedia.so.5
```

I now run the Rpe executable again and I expect it to complain about a different lib file, however it is still complaining about the same `libQt5Multimedia.so.5` file not being found.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT-1**

LDD output:

```
adadacha@duanedibbley:~/sandbox$ ldd Rpe
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7731000)
    libQt5Multimedia.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Network.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Xml.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf7616000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf75f9000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf744a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7404000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x5661f000)
adadacha@duanedibbley:~/sandbox$
```

Comment: And what does `ldd <exename>` say this library should be loaded from?

Comment: @trojanfoe good point, added this to my question : )

Comment: OK so looks like you need to add the libraries to `/usr/local/lib` or someplace?

Comment: @trojanfoe yeah... I could put them there (have not tried yet), but I thought that if you put them in the same folder it should pick them up?

Comment: You can do, however then you'd need to set `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before executing the binary, so that requires a wrapper script.  That's workable if this is a "product" you deliver to a customer as it's all self-contained in a single directory structure.  For something that's not a "product" I would advocate installing into `/usr/local`.

Comment: @trojanfoe ...ohhh, yeah its on windows where you can copy the lib files in the same folder, not linux : |. So to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH I guess I would need to add my install directory, or is it better practise to add "." folder at the end of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: "its on windows"... confused...

Comment: @trojanfoe Sorry, I was just remembering that on windows you can copy the libs into the same folder and it picks them up. On linux it is different (I am using linux) - I think I am getting confused between the two : (    Anyway, if you want to stick this up as an answer I will mark it up : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a directory for your "product" with the executable in a `bin` sub-directory and the Qt libraries (and any other libraries) in a `lib` sub-directory.

In the parent directory I would add a wrapper script to set `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and execute the binary (not tested):

```
#!/bin/sh
dirname="$(dirname "$0")"
exename="$(basename "$0")"

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:"$dirname/lib"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
exec "$dirname/bin/$exename" $*
```